# IBM ServerRAID 6i Battery

Tags: raid, raid-controller

I have an IBM Server which has a Raid Controller ServeRAID-6i. The battery of the Raid Controller is been swelled and I have to change it. I couldn't able to find the battery specification/voltages so I can replace it with the appropriate one.

Battery Part NO. 39R8799 for ServeRAID 6i

How can i find the voltage or battery specifications please help?

Comment: If you can't find this by googling then email the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-51898), you need to order a 02R0986. I'd confirm that with whoever sold it to you though.

Comment: I actually need the battery specification only to purchase the battery on my own.

Comment: That is the part number for the battery on its own, but are you intending on putting some other sort of battery in there? If so, you will void the warranty.

Comment: my server is pretty old there is no warranty so i don't have to worry about it.